# Camel requestBodyAndHeaders() doesn't return the route result

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel route with split/aggregate:

```
from("seda:start")
        .routeId("camelRoute")
        .log("Request: ${body}")
        .split()
        .method(SplitService.class, "splitRequest")
        .parallelProcessing()
        .bean(SendToWorker.class, "sendToQ1(${body}, ${headers})")
        .aggregate(header("corrID"),
                new CustomAggregationStrategy()).completionSize(5)
        .log("Aggregated ${body}")
        .bean(SendToWorker.class, "sendToQ2(${body}, ${headers})")
        .log("Response: ${body}");
```

The last log displays the result correctly. When I call it as

```
@Autowired
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
[...]
Object o = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("seda:start", request, headers)
```

I'm not able to get back the result from the Camel route. **The returned o instance is the request object itself**.

Does anyone have idea what can be wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the splitter with agg strategy to do the split + aggregate, then its done in the same leg.

See the *Split aggregate request/reply sample* at:

- http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

Comment: Thanks Claus for the help, this solved the problem. Originally I wanted to use **aggregate()** following the chapter8 example at https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction/blob/master/chapter8/aggregator/src/test/java/camelinaction/AggregateABCTest.java but **with requestBodyAndHeaders()** and not multiple sendBodyAndHeaders() to get back the final result of the aggregation at the caller. Do you have idea how to do it with aggregate() ?

Answer (score 0):

What about if you set the ExchangePattern to InOut just before sending it to your beans using:

```
...
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.bean(...
```

Comment: According to the Camel API requestBodyAndHeaders(): Sends the body to an endpoint with the specified headers and header values. Uses an ExchangePattern.InOut message exchange pattern.

Comment: Ah apologies, I understood the questions incorrectly